# JPanel not responding to KeyEvents

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keyevent

When I am using `JFrame` and I have a `JPanel` and some other component (like a `JButton`), I assign the <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> keys to the `JFrame(KeyEvent)`, but the `JPanel` doesn't respond when I press a key.

Only when the `JPanel` is the only component in the `JFrame` will the `JPanel` respond to Key Events. How can I change this focus so that the `JFrame` sends Key Events to the `JPanel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all questions relating to `KeyListener` not working, use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it will solve the focus related issues of `KeyListener`

Any suggestions to use `requestFocusInWindow` are hacks and will cause you more issues then they solve. Use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it was designed to help solve this issue

Comment: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: I am just having a hard enough time drawing graphics as it is anyways. I see these people make cool java games with graphics and they make it look so much easier than actually is for me to do it. I am so frustrated with how to make the basic fundamentals of a simple graphics game. It is this barrier that has slowed me down for almost a year now. I don't know what to do! D:

This is the best thing I've made: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v6tacqvth1js5yj/AABDmGHnwCkSF8ipy0pIsIDta?dl=0

Comment: Painting and graphics is complex, making games, even more so, so don't discourage if you don't succeed when you first get started

Comment: I don't even know where to start. Right now I am trying to make a package to handle different shapes and make them move around in a JPanel area. I sometimes just want to give up on it and learn Unity or Unreal. I feel like I am doing more work than I have to. Could we maybe move this discussion to the Java chat? (fish and chips)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664601/draw-two-line-by-keytyped-event-in-java/33664850#33664850), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522458/flipping-rotations-and-images/24523176#24523176), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146965/java-swing-key-input-with-jpanel-added-to-joptionpane/34147249#34147249), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622630/gradually-speeding-a-sprite/16623202#16623202)